# Page loading error on using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to develop a mobile website, but I got stucked at a dialog confirmation box. The website will be redirected to a home.php after successful login and then there is a database fetched values in the fields, when the member hits next>> button it will print the details from the previous home.php page in confirm.php using $_POST[]. I am using http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/

Its working fine and I added a new cancel button to the confirm.php page which will be opened as a dialog pop box along with "Confirm" and "Cancel" buttons. The "Confirm" button will undo the operations done in home.php, its also working fine without any problem. The problem is that the "Cancel" button which will be showing in the dialog box will not go back loading the previous confirm.php page fully. That is it will load the confirm.php page but it wont load it fully.

## Codes

home.php

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>  <html>   <head>    <meta charset="utf-8">    <meta
> name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
> <title>Your Personal Health Record</title>     <link rel= "stylesheet"
> href=
> "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css"
> />
>       <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>    <script src=
> "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
> 
>     </head> 
>     <body> 
> 
>     <div data-role= "page">
>         <div data-role="header">
>     <h1>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</h1>
>     <h1> Your Personal Health Record </h1>
>            <a data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c"
> href="logout.php" rel="external" data-theme="c">
>             <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
>                 <span class="ui-btn-text">Logout</span>
>                 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-l ui-icon-shadow"></span>
>             </span>
>         </a>  </div>    <form action="confirm.php" method="post"> 
>      <div data-role="fieldcontain">  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
>           <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
>           <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $rq['fname']; ?>" />    </fieldset>
>         </div>
>      <div data-role="fieldcontain">  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
>           <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
>           <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php echo $rq['lname']; ?>" />
>      </fieldset>
>         </div> ..... ..... <div data-role="page" id="dialog"><!-- dialog-->
> 
>  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">  <h1>Do you want to
> cancel?</h1>  </div><!-- /header -->
> 
>  <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">  <p>All changes made in the
> previous step will be lost!</p>  <a href="cancel.php"
> data-role="button" data-theme="b">Confirm</a>   <a href="confirm.php"
> data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>    
> </div>  </div> </body>
> 
> </html>
```

confirm.php

```
  ....
    ...
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
         <a href="#dialog" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Cancel</a>
     </div>
    ....
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows:

```
<a href="cancel.php" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Confirm</a>  
<a href="confirm.php" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
```

So your 'Confirm' link is pointed to the cancel.php page and your 'Cancel' link is pointed to the confirm.php page. Shouldn't it be:

```
<a href="confirm.php" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Confirm</a>  
<a href="cancel.php" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
```